# Get SQL command from a Cursor in JAVA (android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

How can i retrieve the sql statement from a cursor, something like the code below:

```
Cursor cursor = AppController.getDBO().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_name", null);
System.out.println(cursor.getSQL()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, as a Cursor may be a non-SQL Cursor like [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

A way to do it would be to follow those steps :

1. Add a custom class which implements [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), and with a member called `sqlStatement`
2. Add a custom method to performs a rawQuery in a class dedicated to SQL management (maybe a one extending [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)), that will return your custom class implementing cursor, and in which you will set the SQL statement.

Yes, it's a bit complicated, but it's the only way I know.

Comment: Yeah! i was thinking to do something like this, but i thought it might be implemented in Cursor as when in debug i see the variable `mQuery` holding the sql statement. Then, i assume from your answer that i will have to do it this way. I actually have a custom Cursor declared in my code so it will not be that hard. Thanks for your reply